# Обратная польская запись. Обработка кода

Tags: c++

Сейчас изучаю программы по вычислению постфиксной формы. Нашел такой пример. Вроде все понял, кроме одного. Где здесь строка ввода самого выражения?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
#include <stack>
using std::stack;

int main() {
    stack <int> stk;
    bool isOk = true;
    char c;
    do {
        //пропуск пробелов
        while (c = cin.peek(), c == ' ' || c == '\t') cin.get();
        //завершение обработки и выход из осн цикла
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n' || c == '=') {
            isOk = false;
            cin.get();
        }
        else {
            int t;
            cin >> t;
            if (cin.fail()) {
                //получаем операнды
                int a, b;
                b = stk.top();
                stk.pop();
                a = stk.top();
                stk.pop();
                //вычисляем
                switch (c) {
                case '+':
                    a += b;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    a -= b;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    a *= b;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    a /= b;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                stk.push(a);
                //восстанавливаем чтение, выносим знак операции из потока ввода
                cin.clear();
                //пропуск считивыаемого знака операции, если за ним не идёт завершение обработки
                if (c = cin.peek(), c != EOF && c != '\n' && c != '=') cin.get();
            }
            else
                stk.push(t);
        }
    } while (isOk);

    cout << stk.top() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызовы `cin.peek()` / `cin.get()` / `cin >> t` требуют наличия данных в буффере ввода, и если их там нет, программа будет ждать ввода. То есть на первом же `cin.peek()` можно ввести всю строку.

Честно говоря мне не очень нравится такой подход так как он смешивает ввод данных и обработку.